# How is a signature using an rvalue ambiguous when signature with value exists?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

when I have both of these signatures, I get a compile error:

```
String& operator+(String&& a, const TCHAR* b)
String operator+(String a, const TCHAR* b)

string.cpp(97): error C2593: 'operator +' is ambiguous
      string.cpp(34): could be 'String &operator +(String &&,const TCHAR *)'
      string.cpp(24): or       'String operator +(String,const TCHAR *)'
```

Aren't they different?????  I feel like performance could be increased if I could use both.  On the other hand, is this ambiguous because the + operator always deals with rvalues?

vc++ 2010 compiler

Comment: Why do you think that those particular two overloads will give you any performance advantage? I assume that `operator+` does not modify the arguments, if so, the second overload is sufficient if your type supports *move-construction*.

Comment: I have String(String&& r) and String& operator = (String&& r).

Comment: So just provide the latter of the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that those are different signatures, but all arguments that can be used with one can also be used with the other, so the compiler cannot possibly disambiguate what function needs to be called depending on the arguments.

You probably meant to provide two overloads that take an *rvalue-reference* and and *lvalue-reference* respectively. Also note that it probably makes no sense to return a reference from the first overload.

Note that using an *rvalue* and *lvalue* reference overloads is only needed if you really need to distinguish between the two use cases, but the general definition of `operator+` does not require that distinction, as it does not modify the arguments. The common way of implementing `operator+` is:

```
T operator+( T lhs, T const & rhs ) {
   return lhs+=rhs;
}
```

Performance can be improved a bit to allow for *moves* on either the first or the second arguments to `operator+`, but that requires 4 different combinations of *lvalue*/*rvalue* in both positions (*lvalue*+*lvalue; *lvalue*+*rvalue*; *rvalue*+*lvalue*; *rvalue*+*rvalue*)

Comment: Returning the reference vs the value tripled the performance of my simple test.

Comment: I tried your example.  { return lhs += rhs; } is almost twice as slow as { lhs += rhs; return lhs; }  I would like to understand why this happens.  Note, the rvalue version is the fastest of all three.  I just thought that I would need a non rvalue version too.

Comment: @johnnycrash: uhm... probably, my bad. you should either use two statements (as you mentioned) or `return std::move(lhs += rhs);`. The issue is that in `return lhs += rhs;` the compiler is not allowed to move out of the *lvalue*-expression as it is not aware that it is an *xvalue*, while in `lhs += rhs; return lhs;` it knows that `lhs` is an *xvalue* (eXpiring value) so it will implicitly move from it. If you want to compare different versions you should post them, otherwise it is hard to comment on *the rvalue-reference is the fastest of the three* (considering it might be UB)

Comment: in the first overload, I use the rvalue to contain the result and I return the reference to it.  I figured the rvalue was about to be trashed anyway, so I could reuse it.

Comment: @johnnycrash: That is UB, the returned reference will be invalid after the completion of the full expression in which the temporary was created. At the same time, if you have `a+b+c` with `a` being an *rvalue* (say `f()`), the first `operator+` will yield an *lvalue* reference and that will force the call to a different overload for the second `operator+`, inhibiting potential moves from there on.

Comment: return a += b  <-- slowest
return *(a += b) <-- faster
a += b; return a; <-- fastest
I'm tempted to think the vc compiler is braindead, but I am sure it is just my lack of understanding.

Comment: @johnnycrash: please write the real full code in the answer, `return *(a+=b);` does not make sense unless you provide `operator*`, but that would have different semantics

Comment: the += operator returns a reference, so I don't need the value operator?  Ohhh...  My * operator was kicking in and returning a char *.

Comment: I still dont see why the signatures are the same.  One is an rvalue.  the compiler should choose that one when it has an rvalue situation!  String& operator = (String&& r)  works with String& operator=(const String& s) without complaining.

Comment: @johnnycrash: **Ambiguous** does not mean **same** on the contrary it means **different** but at the same time it means that the compiler cannot pick one over the other from usage. All arguments that are valid for the overload that take an *rvalue* refenrence are also valid arguments for the overload that takes a value. Assuming `T f();`, the compiler cannot know which of the two to call in `f()+f()`. You can on the other hand overload with *rvalue* and *lvalue* references as those are exclusive: the argument is either an *rvalue* or an *lvalue* so the compiler can pick one overload

Comment: Ok so that answers the question!  Thanks.  So the next question would be, how can I encourage it to use one over the other in this case?

Comment: @johnnycrash: That has been in the answer from the beginning, you **cannot** overload with value and *rvalue-reference*, but you can overload with *lvalue* and *rvalue-references*, and the compiler will pick the appropriate one. In **your** case above, the *value* is the only overload you need to produce.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.  So value is the only overload that will ever be used.  Which means I can use rvalue exclusively.  Can you give me the laymen's reasoning as to why value is the only signature ever used?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20768/discussion-between-david-rodriguez-dribeas-and-johnnycrash)

Comment: @johnnycrash: Check the contents of the chat link above